# SQLite3 Case sensitive like in python 2.7.12

Tags: python-2.7, sqlite

It may be a double, but with search "Python sqlite case sensitive like" couldn't get any results.

I've run into a problem with case sensitive LIKE query in sqlite 3 model on python 2.7. The problem looks like this: LIKE with % is case insensitive.

Here an example:

```
import sqlite3

db = sqlite3.connect("test.db")
db.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS rec(
                id        INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
               name   TEXT );""")
db.commit()
for name in "ABC", "abc", "Abc", "aBC":
    db.execute("INSERT INTO rec(name) VALUES(?);",(name,))

print "A%",db.execute("SELECT name FROM rec WHERE name LIKE ?;",("A%",)).fetchall()
print "a%",db.execute("SELECT name FROM rec WHERE name LIKE ?;",("a%",)).fetchall()
```

The result is quite a surprise:

```
A% [(u'ABC',), (u'abc',), (u'Abc',), (u'aBC',)]
a% [(u'ABC',), (u'abc',), (u'Abc',), (u'aBC',)]
```

Is it possible to tell sqlite to be case sensitive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to execute the SQL statement `"PRAGMA case_sensitive_like = on"` first, then it should work.

Comment: I like @MikeT answer, but yours is most correct one! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The **GLOB** operator may be what you want.

> The GLOB operator is similar to LIKE but uses the Unix file globbing
>   syntax for its wildcards. Also, **GLOB is case sensitive**, unlike LIKE.
>
> [The LIKE, GLOB, REGEXP, and MATCH operators](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html)

- Note The most common wildcards are **`*`**, **`?`**, and **`[…]`** (as opposed to LIKE's `%` and `_` ).

So :-

```
print "A*",db.execute("SELECT name FROM rec WHERE name GLOB ?;",("A*",)).fetchall()
print "a*",db.execute("SELECT name FROM rec WHERE name GLOB ?;",("a*",)).fetchall()
```

Should be less surprising and result in :-

```
A% [(u'ABC',), (u'Abc',)]
a% [(u'abc',), (u'aBC',)]
```

Comment: perfect! Thank you!