# SqlAlchemy like filter case insensitive but it should be case sensitive

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, case-sensitive, case-insensitive

I am using SqlAlchemy for a database, but I have a problem when using like function in queries.

My database is SQLite.

My request is like this:

```
self.session.query(Value.scan).filter(Value.current_value.like("%" + search + "%"), Value.tag == Tag.tag, Tag.visible == True).distinct().all()
```

The column Value.current_value is a String, you can see the declaration here:

```
class Value(Base):
    current_value = Column(String, nullable=False)
```

search variable is a str coming from a rapid search bar, and is case sensitive (I never call lower or upper on it).

I want to do a case sensitive search, but the results are case insensitive.

I did some research and like should be case sensitive, and ilike case insensitive, so I don't understand why it's case insensitive.

Should I choose another type for my column that has to be case sensitive?

Another strange thing is that I have the same problem when using the function contains on the same column (case insensitive result), but not when using operators like ==, !=, <, or > (case sensitive result)

Does semeone knows why it's case sensitive with operators, but not with like and contains functions?

Best regards

Lucie

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: SQLite, sorry I forgot to precise that!

Comment: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#like, SQLite LIKE is case insensitive in the ASCII range by default, it seems. It can be made case sensitive using the [case_sensitive_like pragma](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_case_sensitive_like). SQLAlchemy [`ColumnElement.contains()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.ColumnElement.contains) is simply a shorthand for `col LIKE '%' || expr || '%'`.

Comment: Related, if not a duplicate of [SQLite3 Case sensitive like in python 2.7.12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49039544/sqlite3-case-sensitive-like-in-python-2-7-12)

Comment: I was able to activate the case_sensitive_like pragma, and it's working for both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQLite, [LIKE](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#like) is by default case insensitive.

What I had to do is activating the [case_sensitive_like pragma](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_case_sensitive_like).

I created a class to activate the pragma like this:

```
class ForeignKeysListener(PoolListener):
    """
    Class to activate the pragma case_sensitive_like, that makes the
    like and contains functions case sensitive
    """
    def connect(self, dbapi_con, con_record):
        db_cursor = dbapi_con.execute('pragma case_sensitive_like=ON')
```

When you create the engine, you just have to add the listener like this:

```
engine = create_engine(
    'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(self.folder, 'database', 'mia2.db'),
    listeners=[ForeignKeysListener()])
```

Comment: As a small side note [class based listeners have been deprecated](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/interfaces.html#module-sqlalchemy.interfaces) in favor of the [event system](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/event.html).